# Does Wix Velo have a way to use http-delete protocol or fetch delete?

Tags: velo, http-delete

I have been looking for other people having questions about using the DELETE method with Wix velo.
It is not allowed with fetch.
Why is this? Is there a workaround?

Searched everywhere, tried contacting Wix... can't even find a way to contact them...